# Get Windows batch file parameter by name, not position

Tags: windows, batch-file

If I run a Windows batch file in the following way:

```
myscript.bat -b test -c 789
```

or in the following way:

```
myscript.bat -c 789 -b test
```

What is the best way to reliably get the value of `c`?

Comment: duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973824/windows-bat-file-optional-argument-parsing

Answer (score 2):

how about:

---

```
IF _%1==_b echo do something with %2
IF _%1==_c echo do something with %2
IF _%3==_b echo do something with %4
IF _%3==_c echo do something with %4
```

---