# Batch script that gets commandline parameters

Tags: batch-file

I am completeley new with windows batch scripting. I want to write a batch script that gets commandline parameters as below;

myscript -parameter1 param1 -parameter2 param2

It should set parameter1 to param1 and parameter2 to param2 inside the script.
Does anybody have a code block which does the above?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Bat file optional argument parsing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973824/windows-bat-file-optional-argument-parsing) Take a look at [my recent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8162578/1012053) to this old question - It has some ideas and techniques you may find useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can go through the arguments with a loop and try something like this:

```
:argloop
  set "arg=%~1"
  if "%arg:~0,1%"=="-" (
    set "%arg:~1%=%~2"
    shift
  )
  shift
if not "%1"=="" goto argloop

echo parameter 1: %parameter1%
echo parameter 2: %parameter2%
```

This will look at the arguments one by one and if an argument starts with a `-` it will set an environment variable of the same name with the next argument as its value:

```
H:\>args.cmd -parameter1 param1 -parameter2 param2
parameter 1: param1
parameter 2: param2
```

If you need the original arguments later, then you should move above loop to a subroutine and call it with `%*` as arguments.

Comment: @korhan If it worked for you, then maybe you could think about accepting the answer? Accepting answers will make people more willing to answer you in the future.