# Batch file for parsing command line input that contains comma separated values

Tags: command-line, command-line-arguments, batch-file

I am working on a command line utility that takes set of input parameters as command.
Those input parameters are then validated against predefined names. The utility is invoked in this manner:

**runUtility.cmd**    **-A  -B x,y,z  -C w**

Here parameters are A, B and C (one that starts with -).
Now the validation rules are as follows:

1. Parameter's name should match predefined names, so that one can not pass any invalid parameter say -UVW
2. Parameter may or may not have a value. In above example -A has no value, while -B has x,y,z and -C has w.

I have written this code to validate the inputs:

```
:validate

set argument=%1
set argumentValue=%2


if "%argument%" == "-A" (   
    shift   
    goto validate
)

if "%argument%" == "-B" (
    if "%argumentValue%" == "" (
        echo Empty value for -B
        goto end
    )
    shift
    shift 
    goto validate       
)

if "%argument%" == "-C" (
    if "%argumentValue%" == "" (
        echo Empty value for -C
        goto end
    )
    shift
    shift  
    goto validate      
)

if %argument%" == "" (
        goto end
)

Argument %argument% is invalid

:end
```

But this does not seem to work, as -B has comma separated values, so for B when it does two shifts, in the next iteration,  y becomes %1 and z becomes %2. Since y is not a parameter, it fails with last line of code that "Argument y is invalid".
Actually comma is taken as delimiter by SHIFT command, so x,y,z does remain a single value.

I want x,y,z to be taken as a single value OR is there any other way to process this?
I am bit new to batch scripting , I tried with FOR loop but there I was not able to get %1 and %2 together in every iteration.

Answer (score 10):

Batch uses any combination of space, comma, semicolon, tab, and equal to delimit parameters. If you want to include any of those characters in a parameter, then the parameter must be quoted.

```
runUtility.cmd -A -B "x,y,z" -C w
```

Your script can remove the enclosing quotes with the `~` modifier. It is also a good idea to enclose your entire assignment within quotes to guard against problem characters like `&`, `|`, etc. The double quotes in the assignment below will not be included in the value.

```
set "argumentValue=%~2"
```

I developed an option parser that you might want to look at: [Windows Bat file optional argument parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8162578/1012053).

The parsing code hardly changes regardless what options you define. The only things that have to change are the definition of your options using a single variable, the `SHIFT /3` should be modified to `SHIFT /1`, every `%~3` becomes `%~1`, and `%~4` becomes `%~2`.

The option parser has the ability to automatically supply default values for unspecified options.

Assuming you do not have default values, your options would be defined as

```
set "options=-A: -B:"" -C:"""
```

Meaning an `-A` option that does not take a value, and `-B` and `-C` options that take values but by default are undefined.

The options are stored in variables that match the option name (dash included).

Comment: EDIT - I corrected the list of changes that must be made to the linked option parser if it is to be used for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something to get you going, it is based on 3 parameters, A B C, and each having up to 3 parameters separated by a space. It's unfinished as I don't have time to put it all together but it should give you something to work with, which you can tweak as you need.

```
@echo off
set p1=%1
set p2=%2
set p3=%3
set p4=%4
set params=(-A -B -C)
for %%x in %params% do (
if "%p1%"=="" (
echo No parameters given
exit /b >nul
) else (
if "%p1%"=="%%x" (
if not "%p4%"=="" (
echo %%x has 3 parameters
) else (
if not "%p3%"=="" (
echo %%x has 2 parameters
) else (
if not "%p2%"=="" (
echo %%x has 1 parameter
)
)
)
)
)
)
```

Comment: The idea is to validate the parameters for their names and empty values. But when we get comma separated value for any parameter, the code fails. I don't think above solution will work for it. Any suggestion is welcome.