# Windows batch command to parse input arguments within a range

Tags: batch-file, args

If a user were to input: "program.bat --execute -s 1000 -r 60"

How can I extract the input as one string starting from "-s" to the end (the end could have unlimited number of parameters). In this case, I'd want "-s 1000 -r 60".

I want to do something like:

```
if "%1"=="--execute"
   grab the rest of the arguments
```

I know %* grabs all the arguments, but I only want -s till the end.

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13311756/62576) and it's accepted answer not help you?

Comment: Nothing I know of. I'd write a small utility program that would process the %*  string, or use a regex processor.

Answer (score 0):

You already know that `%*` starts with `--execute`, so it is safe to delete everything up through the first occurrance of `--execute`.

```
set args=%*
if %1 equ --execute echo args=%args:*--execute=%
```