# Batch For Loop: Use wildcard character in string

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, wildcard, glob

I have been translating some shell code to MS-DOS Batch.  In my code, I have the sample:

```
for %%i in (%*) do set "clargs=!clargs! %%i"
```

If I input the argument "-?" (without the quotation marks), it is not added to clargs.  I assume it is because '?' is a wildcard character.  Is there anything I can do to ensure that for does not do special things because of the question mark being located in the argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, the wild card characters `*` and `?` are always expanded when used within a FOR IN() clause. Unfortunately, there is no way to prevent the wildcard expansion.

You cannot use a FOR loop to access all parameters if they contain wildcards. Instead, you should use a GOTO loop, along with the SHIFT command.

```
set clargs=%1
:parmLoop
if "%~1" neq "" (
  set clargs=%clargs% %1
  shift /1
  goto :parmLoop
)
```

Although your sample is quite silly, since the resultant `clargs` variable ends up containing the same set of values that were already in `%*`. If you simply want to set a variable containing all values, simply use `set clargs=%*`

More typically, an "array" of argument variables is created.

```
set argCnt=0
:parmLoop
if "%~1" equ "" goto :parmsDone
set /a argCnt+=1
set arg%argCnt%=%1
shift /1
goto :parmLoop
:parmsDone

:: Working with the "array" of arguments is best done with delayed expansion
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /l %%N in (1 1 %argCnt%) do echo arg%%N = !arg%%N!
```

See [Windows Bat file optional argument parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8162578/1012053) for a robust method to process unix style arguments passed to a Windows batch script.

Comment: I agree it was very silly--I was thinking of replacing it with a better sample but it was the best line to display what I meant.  The actual code sample is about 20 lines long now which I didn't feel was necessary to show what I meant.  I will try out this sample tomorrow and if it works I will mark your answer as correct.  Thanks!

Comment: So I have http://pastebin.com/bDABiTy6 and it works, but how would I loop through the values of args in a similar manner, as args could contain "-?" and then the for loop interpreting args would ignore it.

Comment: @Sammidysam - Huh? What FOR loop are you referring to? There isn't any FOR loop in my answer, nor is there a FOR loop in your pastebin code.

Comment: Oh, sorry.  I meant http://pastebin.com/GfMkub1X which is my for loop to take the arguments put into the program and interpret them.  The program initially splits up the command line arguments into arguments for gcc/g++ and arguments for the program calling gcc/g++.

Comment: Do I need to just interpret the arguments for the program in the loop separating libraries for gcc/g++ and arguments for the program?

Comment: @Sammidysam - Presumably you are doing something like `set args=%*`. Don't do that :-) Use the loop construct in this answer, but don't store all the arguments in one variable. Instead, set a new variable for each argument found.

Comment: The second code comes after the first.  Sorry for not clarifying that.  So you mean that I make a variable that stores whether each argument has come up, and then instead of looping through the list of arguments for the program I just check what arguments are there (by checking if the variable for the argument being present represents true)?

Comment: @Sammidysam - Something like that. Have a look at my updated answer.

Comment: In your second sample, the first argument is skipped.  Adding a simple firstTime variable fixes it though.  Thank you VERY much!  The code works great!

Comment: @Sammidysam - You are correct, I had the SHIFT in the wrong location. I fixed the code in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET dummy=%*
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%f IN ('set dummy') DO CALL :addme %%g
ECHO %clargs%
GOTO :eof

:addme
IF "%~1"=="" GOTO :EOF 
IF DEFINED clargs SET clargs=%clargs% %1
IF NOT DEFINED clargs SET clargs=%1
SHIFT
GOTO addme
```

I severly doubt you'll get a completely bullet-proof solution. The above solution will drop separators (comma, semicolon, equals) for instance. Other solutions may have problems with close-parentheses; there's the perpetual `%` and `^` problems - but it will handle `-?`

But for your purposes, from what you've shown, what's wrong with

```
set clargs=%clargs% %*
```

(No doubt you'll want to process further, but ve haff vays...)