# How to pass paramaters like unix into windows batch file

Tags: validation, batch-file, parameters, cmd

I need pass various parameters into a **.cmd file** with unix format

> file.cmd -Configuration=value -Source=value -flag

But, i try this:

```
StartLocal

@ECHO off
CLS

SETLOCAL
SET CMDLINE=%*
SET Configuration=
SET Source=
SET BADARGS=
SET VALIDATION=
GOTO main

:SplitArgs
  echo SplitArgs(%*)
  if "%*" NEQ "" (
    for /F "tokens=1,2,* delims== " %%i in ("%*") do call :AssignKeyValue %%i %%j & call :SplitArgs %%k
  )
  goto :eof

:AssignKeyValue
  echo   AssignKeyValue(%1, %2)
  if /i %1==-Configuration (
    SET Configuration=%2
  ) else if /i %1==-Source (
    SET Source=%2
  ) else (
    REM Append unrecognised [key,value] to BADARGS
    echo Unknown KEY %1
    SET BADARGS=%BADARGS%[%1, %2]
  )
  goto :eof

:Validate
 echo Validating
 SET VALIDATION=FAIL
 if defined Configuration (
   echo   -Configuration ok
   if defined Source (
     echo   -Source ok
       if NOT defined BADARGS (
         SET VALIDATION=SUCCESS
       )
   )
 )
 goto :eof

:main
  cls
  call :SplitArgs %CMDLINE%
  call :Validate
  if "%VALIDATION%" EQU "SUCCESS" (
    ECHO -Configuration = %Configuration%
    ECHO -Source = %Source%
  )
```

But i have a problems, because when i write a parameter in this mode

> file.cmd Source=value

always take the value,i need validate this, some idea... thank you

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking, but your algorithm will not work very well if you have a mixture of flags and name/value pairs. You really should try the solution at http://stackoverflow.com/a/8162578/1012053. I updated the code in that answer to show how to use the variable once it has been assigned. The CMD parser will treat `=` as a `<space>`, so `-name=value` and `-name value` will give the same result.

Comment: Thank you man... it's very good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
file.cmd "Source=value"
```

Comment: I wish validate this i'm not want this source=value i want only this -source=value

Comment: put the parameter in double quotes.