# Extract the last mail from a mbox file

Tags: python, mbox

I have a mbox file that contains many emails,I tried this code that typically reads all messages,what i want is to read and print only the last email of the mbox file and store it alone in another mbox file.
This is the simple code that I wrote:

```
import mailbox

for msg in mailbox.mbox('C:\\Users\\hmk\Desktop\\PFE 2019\\ML\\MachineLearningPhishing-master\\MachineLearningPhishing-master\\code\\resources\\mboxfile.mbox'):
print(msg)
```

Comment: `all_messages = mailbox.mbox(..)` `print(all_messages[-1])` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has a syntax error; the line after the `for` loop should be indented. But actually the solution to your problem is to move it outside the loop. Then you just need to put something else inside the loop.

```py
import mailbox

for msg in mailbox.mbox('C:\\Users\\hmk\Desktop\\PFE 2019\\ML\\MachineLearningPhishing-master\\MachineLearningPhishing-master\\code\\resources\\mboxfile.mbox'):
    pass
# We are now outside the loop, and `msg` contains the last message
print(msg)
```

Of course, a better fix is to not loop at all.

```
messages = mailbox.mbox('C:\\Users\\hmk\Desktop\\PFE 2019\\ML\\MachineLearningPhishing-master\\MachineLearningPhishing-master\\code\\resources\\mboxfile.mbox')
print(messages[messages.keys()[-1]])
```

The above assumes you are on a Python version which is new enough to keep dictionaries sorted in insertion order. If not, you probably do need the loop after all.

As a final aside, probably don't hardcode absolute file paths. Make your program accept a file name argument, so you can run it on any mbox file in any directory.

```
import mailbox
import sys

messages = mailbox.mbox(sys.argv[1])
print(messages[messages.keys()[-1]])
```

Call it like

```
python3 lastmsg.py C:\Users\hmkDesktop\PFE 2019\ML\MachineLearningPhishing-master\MachineLearningPhishing-master\code\resources\mboxfile.mbox >last
```

Obviously, a production script should have some error checking and help etc but I leave those as an exercise.

Comment: On Python 3.7, using `messages[-1]` raises a `KeyError`.  Using `messages[len(messages)-1]` works.

Comment: Thanks, and for the part where i should call it how can i do it using a batch script

Comment: Friends don't let friends use Windows but that should be completely trivial. Quick googling got me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21582886/creating-a-windows-batch-file-that-accepts-parameters

Comment: But let me figure out Roland's comment, he is right, it returns a hash not a list.

Comment: When I executed it on jupyter notebook it worked fine, but when i used batch script it gave me an error `Key Error: ne message with key -1`

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what my previous comment talks about. See updated answer now.

Comment: @tripleee yes i tried it with you syntax in a batch file and it didn't work
Here is my batch script
`@echo off
set VAR_1= "C:\Users\hmk\Desktop\PFE 2019\ML\MachineLearningPhishing-master\MachineLearningPhishing-master\code\resources\email-enron.mbox"
python get_last_mail.py %1 %VAR_1
pause`

Comment: Probably ask a new question if you can't figure it out. I am the only one who sees your comments here and I really can't help with `cmd` questions. Putting code in comments doesn't work very well, as you can see; though I guess the space after the equals sign might be a problem.