# Adding switches to command line arguments

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd

I want to create my own command in following manner which I wish to run from both batch and cmd.exe:

```
fake-command -name <some value> -age <some Value>
```

Currently I know to create a command as following:

```
fake-command  <some value> <another Value>
```

After that I can collect the input as `%1` and `%2`. But that is no efficient way to do this because what happens if the order in which I am expecting the input gets changed and someone enters age before name.

So I have two questions:

1. How to create Linux like switches on Windows command line?
2. Is my approach correct? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Are you talking about a batch file, a powershell script, or an executable?

Comment: batch file and cmd.exe  @James

Comment: Have a look at [my answer to "Windows Bat file optional argument parsing"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8162578/1012053). It supports default values and is really convenient. I've used the technique on batch scripts with 20 named options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "switches=name age whatever"
SET "noargs=option anotheroption"
SET "swindicators=/ -"
SET "otherparameters="
:: clear switches
FOR %%a IN (%switches% %noargs%) DO SET "%%a="

:swloop
IF "%~1"=="" GOTO process

FOR %%a IN (%swindicators%) DO (
 FOR %%b IN (%noargs%) DO (
  IF /i "%%a%%b"=="%~1" SET "%%b=Y"&shift&GOTO swloop
 )
 FOR %%b IN (%switches%) DO (
  IF /i "%%a%%b"=="%~1" SET "%%b=%~2"&shift&shift&GOTO swloop
 )
)
SET "otherparameters=%otherparameters% %1"
SHIFT
GOTO swloop

:process

FOR %%a IN (%switches% %noargs% otherparameters) DO IF DEFINED %%a (CALL ECHO %%a=%%%%a%%) ELSE (ECHO %%a NOT defined)

GOTO :EOF
```

Here's a demonstration.

Given you have 3 switches, **name** **age** **whatever** which accept one argument and two true switches, **option** and **anotheroption** which take no arguments, then running the above procedure as

**q27497516 -age 92 /option goosefeathers /name fred**

(q27497516.bat is my batchname here) will yield

```
name=fred
age=92
whatever NOT defined
option=Y
anotheroption NOT defined
otherparameters= goosefeathers
```

Convention is to use `/` as a switch indicator - a leading `-` is legitimate for a filename. Implementation depends on the programmer's whim. The above structure will allow any character - within `cmd`'s syntax rules, naturally [ie. $_# OK, %!^ No, ! maybe () awkward]

Comment: excellent! I have saved it on my ***golden BAT snippets*** folder