# Passing argument in batch file

Tags: batch-file, command-line-arguments

Have seen passing argument to a batch file something like

filename.bat argument1 argument2 ..

But i want to pass something like 
filename.bat username=argument1 password=argument2

As i dont want to depend on any order , user can pass password first and then username.

Comment: This is possible, take a look at this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/176497/DOS-Batch-how-to-parse-command-line-in-DOS-batch-f). But, implementing the same in some scripting language is much easier like vbs

Comment: Not exactly what you asked for, but you should take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/8162578/1012053

Answer (score 2):

Look here : [processing switches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27497516/adding-switches-to-command-line-arguments/27497837#27497837)

Although this is oriented toward using the format `/username argument1` it's relatively easy to adapt to `username=argument1` **but** there is a problem with `=` when passed within "a" parameter - it's seen as a separator, so the receiving routine would see two parameters, but they'd be paired (username *and* argument1.)

Really depends on quite how you want to process the data. You can, if you so desire, pass the parameter `"quoted"` to get over the `= is a separator` problem, then use

```
 for /f "tokens=1,*delims==" %%a in ("%~1") do set "%%a=%%b"
```

but remembering to use the quoting may be a stumbling block.

Note: using the procedure I've pointed to is not restricted by parameter-count.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you are able to pass parameters in a random order, as they are not identified by a parameter name, but by %0 - %9

see http://www.robvanderwoude.com/parameters.php

As mentioned here, you can use up tp 9 parameters when calling a batch file..

Comment: You could exploid the parameters maybee by doing this:

%0 "password" string to identify what is coming next
%1 "<the actual password>"
%2 "user" string to identify that the next param is the user name
%3 "<the actual user name>"

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by using a [variable substring](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) since username= and password= are both 9 character long.

For example

```
set temp=%0
set temp=%temp:~0,9% 
if %temp%=="username=" (
  set tmpUser=%0
  set username=%tmpUser:~9%
  set tmpPass=%1
  set password=%tmpPass:~9%
)
if %temp%=="password=" (
  set tmpPass=%0
  set password=%tmpPass:~9%
  set tmpUser=%1
  set username=%tmpUser:~9%
)
```

Comment: substring syntax only works with variables not with parameters like `%1`