# Forward slash in last argument causes path to directory of batch file ("%~dp0") to change

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-line-arguments

I am learning a bit how to work with parameters in a batch-script and ended up creating some kind of template for reading arguments and setting parameters

```
@echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set needextra=
set errstat=
set noflag=
set param_f=Not set yet
set param_g=You didn't use G-flag

:readARGS
IF [%1] == [] goto :endARGS
call :arg_%1 2> nul
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 call :arg_default %1
SHIFT
IF DEFINED needextra (
    set %needextra%=%~1
    SHIFT
    set needextra=
)
goto :readARGS
:endARGS
echo path to directory of batch script: %~dp0
echo    - noflag:  !noflag!
echo    - param_f: !param_f!
echo    - param_g: !param_g!
EndLocal
exit /b 0
```

The first echo that prints the directory is important for my question (see later) 
After that I create a function for each flag (`arg_/flag`) and one for arguments without a flag (the `arg_default`):

```
:arg_/f           -- flag f: set param_f to value of next argument
set needextra=param_f
exit /b 0

:arg_/g           -- flag g: just set the param_g to a value
set param_g=You used the G-flag
exit /b 0

:arg_default      -- default, neither flag f or g: just set the noflag
echo noflag=%~1
exit /b 0
```

When I put everything in a batch-file, let's say `C:\Users\user\scripts\params.bat` and put the directory in the path I can execute the script:

```
> params "just an arg"
path to directory of batch script: C:\Users\user\scritpts\
   - noflag:  just an arg
   - param_f: Not set yet
   - param_g: You didn't use G-flag
> params another /G /F "this is f"
path to directory of batch script: C:\Users\user\scritpts\
   - noflag:  another
   - param_f: this is f
   - param_g: You used the G-flag
```

The fact I put it in functions allows me to enter the parameters in whatever order I wish but if I put the G-flag as last I get this strange behaviour:

```
> params /F "this is f again" bizar /G
path to directory of batch script: C:\
   - noflag:  bizar
   - param_f: this is f again
   - param_g: You used the G-flag
```

The `%~dp0` returns only `C:\`! I tried it with other parameters, moved the batch-file to another directory, called it within the directory, the `%~dp0` kept returning only `C:\`. In fact each time the last argument contains a "/" the `%~dp0` will behave "strangely" like in this example:

```
> params /G /F stranger "what happens /here"
path to directory of batch script: C:\Users\user\script\what happens \
   - noflag:  what happens /here
   - param_f: stranger
   - param_g: You used the G-flag
```

Can someone please explain me why this is happening? I cannot figure out why and could not find anything on the web either. I use Windows 10

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why this

```
params "just an arg"
params another /G /F "this is f"
```

works and this

```
params /G /F stranger "what happens /here"
params /F "this is f again" bizar /G
```

doesn't work is ... that in both cases it does not work!

As Magoo points, your problem is the `shift` command. By default it shifts **all** the arguments, so the tenth argument is stored in `%9`, the old `%9` is stored in `%8` ... and `%1` is stored in `%0`, losing the reference to the current batch file.

In your code you are shifting all the arguments until all are processed. This leaves the last argument inside `%0`, and at this moment things become interesting.

When `%~dp0` is requested, the last argument is stored inside `%0` and, as we ask for the drive and folder of the element referenced inside the argument, `cmd` tries to resolve it assumming you know what you ask for and the variable contains a valid reference to a element in the file system, converts it to a absolute path and then retrieve the requested elements.

And here you have faced two cases

- `%0` contains just a simple string without slashes or backslashes. `cmd` handles it as a file name that is stored in the current active directory, so, as you request a drive and path, the drive and path of the current active directory are retrieved. In your "working" cases you end with

```dos
"C:\Users\user\script\just an arg" -> %~dp0 = "C:\Users\user\script\"
"C:\Users\user\script\this is f"   -> %~dp0 = "C:\Users\user\script\"
```

- `%0` contains a string with slashes or backslashes. It is the same case that before BUT the string contains a relative path (first failing case) that is prefixed with the current active directory or with a path from the root folder (second failing case) so you end with

```dos
"C:\Users\user\script\what happens /here" -> %~dp0 = "C:\Users\user\script\what happens "
"C:/g" -> %~dp0 = "C:\"
```

How can you solve it?

The easiest way to solve it could be, as proposed by Magoo, to save the value of the `%0` argument before doing any shifting of the arguments.

Another option is to change `shift` commands into `shift /1`, to signal that the shifting will start at the first argument, leaving `%0` unchanged.

If none of this options can be used you can still retrieve a reference to the batch file from inside a subroutine

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Ensure %0 is discarded    
    shift
    echo %0

    call :getCurrentBatchFolder dp0
    echo %dp0%

    exit /b

:getCurrentBatchFolder returnVar
    set "%~1=%~dp0"
    goto :eof
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your complete explanation! I espacially like your `SHIFT /1` solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that `%~d0` is likely to be unreliable following a `SHIFT` command, so I'd save its value at the start.

Perhaps [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27497516) may be of assistance. I'd still save `~dp0` first though...

Comment: thanks a lot. Unfortunately I can't upvote your answer right now because I'm still new. your link redirects to this same question though :p