# Batch Script. How to create a user input with options. Like windows cmd with -s -e

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting, menu

I would like to create a like how we type in CMD with options behind the command. 
For example cmd shutdown /i 
Code:

```
ECHO 1. Nmap
ECHO 2. Nesus
ECHO 3. Nexpose
ECHO ................................

CHOICE /C 123 /M "Enter your choice:"


IF ERRORLEVEL 3 GOTO n
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO ns
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO nx

:n
CALL n.bat
GOTO :eof

:ns
CALL ns.bat
GOTO :eof

:nx
CALL nx.bat
GOTO :eof
```

I would like to transform this into command with options 
For example: script /n /ns

This will execute the code called script with /n (Nmap) and /ns (Nessus)
So that user next time will not need to go through the menu.

and method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding switches to command line arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27497516/adding-switches-to-command-line-arguments)

Answer (score 0):

From another answer of the user in StackOverflow.

It only a method to solve your problem.

Another useful tip is to use %* to mean "all". For example,

```
echo off
set arg1=%1
set arg2=%2
shift
shift
fake-command /u %arg1% /p %arg2% %*
```

When you run:

```
test-command admin password foo bar
```

the above batch file will run:

```
fake-command /u admin /p password foo bar
```

Comment: But they're not running a command, they're running different scripts based on what options were passed in.