# Batch : how to use flagged key parameters in batch script

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

For my batch script I'm want to know how to use some self defined parameters in my batch script. For example :

```
MyBatch.bat -env:Test
```

or

```
MyBatch.bat env=Test
```

I want to know how to parse the value behind the key in my batch script?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/8162578/1012053

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use parameters inside a batch-file, you use variables like `%~1` (note the `~` is there to get rid of quotes around a parameter) if you then have a key value pair as parameter, you could do this

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:=" %%i in ("%~1") do (
  echo %%i %%j
)
```

Note that `=` normally counts as a delimiter, causing your batch file to see `env=Test` as `%~1` is `env`, `%~2` is `Test`. If you want the above solution to work with both, you should use

```
MyBatch.bat env:Test
```

and

```
MyBatch.bat "env=Test"
```

For more information about arguments, see [this](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)