# Add argument to specific batch file

Tags: batch-file

How can I add an additional option to calling changeName.bat?

I want to configure `-h` (Help) to call `changeName.bat -h`

Comment: Maybe check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973824/windows-bat-file-optional-argument-parsing and tell if it helped you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution for your case:

```
@ECHO OFF

IF NOT "%1"=="" (
    IF "%1"=="-h" (
        ECHO This is the help text.
        GOTO end
    )
)

REM Add your instructions below and delete this line
ECHO Hello!

:end
```

HTH ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can directly `goto`the arguments :

```
@echo off

If not "%~1"=="" goto:%~1 2>nul || Echo Error Invalid Argument

echo Here Your normal code without argument
exit/b

:-h
echo I'm In Help
exit/b


:-t
echo I'm in Test
exit/b
```

This is a very robust solution :

- Invalid argument are directly treated without `IF` statement
- Just create a new label to add a new parameter
- You're code is well structured