# Is it possible to have my own named parameters when running a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I would like to know if it is possible to use my own named parameters when running a batch file.

For example I have a deploy.bat and I would like to call it from my command line like, does not matter if I will user double or single dashes:

```
C:\> deploy.bat --user=admin --password=1234
```

Is that possible?

Comment: With regard to the linked duplicate question above, pay particular attention to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8162578/1012053), as it gives a rather elegant solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two ways (other approaches are possible too) , assuming arguments will be the same as in the question:

```
@echo off
:: mind that '=' will be taken as blank space when parsing arguments.
:: and `--user=admin` are two arguments.

:: 1) with for /l
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
rem max count of the expected arguments
set max_count=10


for /l %%# in (1,2,%max_count%) do (
    set /a next=%%#+1
    set curr=%%#
    call set "%%~!curr!=%%~!next!" 2>nul
)
echo %--user% -- %--password%

:::::::::::::::::
:: 2) processing the arguments line
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "prev="
set "current="



for %%a in (%*) do (
    set "current=%%~a"
    if  defined prev (
        set "!prev!=%%~a"
        set "prev="
    ) else (
        set prev=%%a
    )
)

echo %--user% -- %--password%
```

**Explanation:** 
With the both ways I'm proccessing the arguments through one. Also the `=` sign is a standard delimiter for cmd.exe and it will be threated as blank space.

1)In the first approach I'm processing all arguments with `FOR /L` loop (it acts like the for loop in the c-like syntax languages) with step 2 and on each step I also have the next number.Under delayed expansion I can parametrize the number of the argument and get it like `call echo %%~!number!` which allows me to use a argument-value couple to set the variables. One impediment is you can't process more than 9 arguments in this way (or you'll have to add `shift` somewhere in the loop)

2) In the second one I'm processing the whole argument line.I have one additional variable `prev` that is deleted on each even step and on each odd step it takes the value of the current argument.So on each even step I have argument-value couple.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much. That actually does the job. Can I have an explanation of the above solution?

Comment: @Panagiotis - check my edit.

Comment: All clear. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Batch files support positional parameters only, and are addressed as `%1`, `%2`, etc. If you want to go through the exercise of parsing strings manually - possible, but not a trivial exercise - you can simulate this, but it's probably not worth the effort.

PowerShell is a much richer scripting environment, and does support named parameters.