# Specify command line arguments like name=value pairs for shell script

Tags: shell, tcsh

Is it possible to pass command line arguments to shell script as name value pairs, something like

```
myscript action=build module=core
```

and then in my script, get the variable like 
`$action` and process it?

I know that $1....and so on can be used to get variables, but then won't be name value like pairs. Even if they are, then the developer using the script will have to take care of declaring variables in the same order. I do not want that.

Comment: I think your answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642707/shell-script-argument-parsing

Comment: Yes, as opposed to the bash builtin `getopts`, `getopt` works with tcsh as well.

Comment: I guess something like that is available only for bash.Sorry I didnt specify, Im using tcsh.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Bourne shell, there is a seldom-used option '`-k`' which automatically places any values specified as `name=value` on the command line into the environment.  Of course, the Bourne/Korn/POSIX shell family (including bash) also do that for `name=value` items before the command name:

```
name1=value1 name2=value2 command name3=value3 -x name4=value4 abc
```

Under normal POSIX-shell behaviour, the `command` is invoked with `name1` and `name2` in the environment, and with four arguments.  Under the Bourne (and Korn and bash, but not POSIX) shell `-k` option, it is invoked with `name1`, `name2`, `name3`, and `name4` in the environment and just two arguments.  The `bash` manual page (as in `man bash`) doesn't mention the equivalent of `-k` but it works like the Bourne and Korn shells do.
I don't think I've ever used it (the `-k` option) seriously.

There is no way to tell from within the script (`command`) that the environment variables were specified solely for this command; they are simply environment variables in the environment of that script.

This is the closest approach I know of to what you are asking for.  I do not think anything equivalent exists for the C shell family.  I don't know of any other argument parser that sets variables from `name=value` pairs on the command line.

---

With some fairly major caveats (it is relatively easy to do for simple values, but hard to deal with values containing shell meta-characters), you can do:

```
case $1 in
(*=*) eval $1;;
esac
```

This is not the C shell family.  The `eval` effectively does the shell assignment.

```
arg=name1=value1
echo $name1
eval $arg
echo $name1
```

Comment: I've tried to find information for passing environmental variables to commands like `name=value command`. However I cannot find any explanation in `man bash`. Is there any man page documenting this?

Comment: I just found it in `man bash`: *The environment for any simple command or function may be  augmented  temporarily by  prefixing  it  with  parameter assignments, as described above in PARAMETERS. These assignment statements affect only the environment seen by that command.*

Comment: Several sections of the Bash manual discuss the setting the environment before the command name. One is [Simple Command Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Simple-Command-Expansion).  Another is the section on [Environment](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Environment) and that provides pointers to `-k` via [The Set Built-in](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Set-Builtin).

Answer (score 18):

This worked for me:

```
for ARGUMENT in "$@"
do
   KEY=$(echo $ARGUMENT | cut -f1 -d=)

   KEY_LENGTH=${#KEY}
   VALUE="${ARGUMENT:$KEY_LENGTH+1}"

   export "$KEY"="$VALUE"
done

# from this line, you could use your variables as you need

cd $FOLDER
mkdir $REPOSITORY_NAME
```

Usage

```
bash my_scripts.sh  FOLDER="/tmp/foo" REPOSITORY_NAME="stackexchange"
```

**FOLDER** and **REPOSITORY_NAME** are ready to use in the script.

It does not matter what order the arguments are in.

### Changelog

- [v1.0.0](https://gist.github.com/jrichardsz/c0047f58cb6765c7b6a7fb33c466ab3f#file-args_shell_parser-v1-0-0-md)

Comment: Thanks. Is there a windows equivalent for batch scripts?

Comment: Theoretically, you can replicate this script in windows using its own commands. Here some links with complex windows bats if you need : - https://github.com/krichter722/squirrel-sql/blob/master/archive/squirrel-sql/app/cmd/squirrel-sql.bat
- https://github.com/apache/tomcat/tree/master/bin

Answer (score 2):

```
env action=build module=core myscript
```

You said you're using tcsh.  For Bourne-based shells, you can drop the "env", though it's harmless to leave it there.  Note that this applies to the shell from which you run the command, not to the shell used to implement `myscript`.

If you specifically want the name=value pairs to follow the command name, you'll need to do some work inside `myscript`.

Comment: on bash RHEL this is working for me even without env prefix; is env prefix important?

Comment: @spioter `env` is an external command, typically `/usr/bin/env`, that updates the environment and invokes the specified command. In bash, `action=build module=core myscript` does essentially the same thing; it invokes `myscript` with those two entries added to the environment. (In both cases, the environment updates do not persist past the execution of `myscript`.) The `env` command still has its uses, but it's not needed in this case.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite an old question, but still valid
I have not found the cookie cut solution. I combined the above answers. For my needs I created this solution; this works even with `white space` in the argument's value.

Save this as `argparse.sh`

```sh
#!/bin/bash

: ${1?
  'Usage:
  $0 --<key1>="<val1a> <val1b>" [ --<key2>="<val2a> <val2b>" | --<key3>="<val3>" ]'
}

declare -A args
while [[ "$#" > "0" ]]; do
  case "$1" in 
    (*=*)
        _key="${1%%=*}" &&  _key="${_key/--/}" && _val="${1#*=}"
        args[${_key}]="${_val}"
        (>&2 echo -e "key:val => ${_key}:${_val}")
        ;;
  esac
  shift
done
(>&2 echo -e "Total args: ${#args[@]}; Options: ${args[@]}")

## This additional can check for specific key
[[ -n "${args['path']+1}" ]] && (>&2 echo -e "key: 'path' exists") || (>&2 echo -e "key: 'path' does NOT exists");
```

@Example: Note, arguments to the script can have optional prefix `--`

```sh
./argparse.sh --x="blah"
./argparse.sh --x="blah" --yy="qwert bye"
./argparse.sh x="blah" yy="qwert bye"
```

Some interesting use cases for this script:

```sh
./argparse.sh --path="$(ls -1)"
./argparse.sh --path="$(ls -d -1 "$PWD"/**)"
```

Above script created as gist, Refer: [argparse.sh](https://gist.github.com/mangalbhaskar/7b19616fe9ddfbc0923b71b220fbfe51)

Answer (score 0):

Extending on Jonathan's answer, this worked nicely for me:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$#" -eq "0" ]; then
  echo "Error! Usage: Remind me how this works again ..."
  exit 1
fi

while [[ "$#" > "0" ]]
do
  case $1 in
    (*=*) eval $1;;
  esac
shift
done
```