# Is there a way to avoid positional arguments in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have to write a function in bash. The function will take about 7 arguments. I know that I can call a function like this:

To call a function with parameters:

```
function_name $arg1 $arg2
```

And I can refer my parameters like this inside the function:

```
function_name () {
   echo "Parameter #1 is $1"
}
```

My question is, is there a better way refer to the parameters inside the function? Can I avoid the $1, $2, $3, .... thing and simply use the $arg1, $arg2, ...?

Is there a proper method for this or do I need to re-assign these parameters to some other variables inside the function? E.g.:

```
function_name () {
   $ARG1=$1
   echo "Parameter #1 is $ARG1"
}
```

Any example would be much appreciated.

Comment: What's the difference between using `$1` vs `$ARG1`?

Comment: @JonLin: I can use more intuitive name, instead of $1, $2. The numbers are confusing.

Comment: Do you really require seven mandatory parameters? A common approach would be to turn as many as possible into options, and supply a default value where it makes sense. It makes your script a lot easier to use if you don't have to memorize a particular positional order for such a large number of arguments, even if most users would override the default values most of the time.

Comment: Hey @Bhushan! I think I have a solution for you. I've posted an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128296/is-there-a-way-to-avoid-positional-arguments-in-bash/30031775#30031775

Comment: This question looks like : [Specify command line arguments like name=value pairs for shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43008569/3957754)

Answer (score 125, accepted):

The common way of doing that is assigning the arguments to local variables in the function, i.e.:

```
copy() {
    local from=${1}
    local to=${2}

    # ...
}
```

---

Another solution may be *getopt*-style option parsing.

```
copy() {
    local arg from to
    while getopts 'f:t:' arg
    do
        case ${arg} in
            f) from=${OPTARG};;
            t) to=${OPTARG};;
            *) return 1 # illegal option
        esac
    done
}

copy -f /tmp/a -t /tmp/b
```

---

Sadly, bash can't handle long options which *would* be more readable, i.e.:

```
copy --from /tmp/a --to /tmp/b
```

For that, you either need to use the external `getopt` program (which I think has long option support only on GNU systems) or implement the long option parser by hand, i.e.:

```
copy() {
    local from to

    while [[ ${1} ]]; do
        case "${1}" in
            --from)
                from=${2}
                shift
                ;;
            --to)
                to=${2}
                shift
                ;;
            *)
                echo "Unknown parameter: ${1}" >&2
                return 1
        esac

        if ! shift; then
            echo 'Missing parameter argument.' >&2
            return 1
        fi
    done
}

copy --from /tmp/a --to /tmp/b
```

Also see: [using getopts in bash shell script to get long and short command line options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402377/using-getopts-in-bash-shell-script-to-get-long-and-short-command-line-options)

---

You can also be lazy, and just pass the 'variables' as arguments to the function, i.e.:

```
copy() {
    local "${@}"

    # ...
}

copy from=/tmp/a to=/tmp/b
```

and you'll have `${from}` and `${to}` in the function as local variables.

Just note that the same issue as below applies — if a particular variable is not passed, it will be inherited from parent environment. You may want to add a 'safety line' like:

```
copy() {
    local from to    # reset first
    local "${@}"

    # ...
}
```

to ensure that `${from}` and `${to}` will be unset when not passed.

---

And if something *very bad* is of your interest, you could also assign the arguments as global variables when invoking the function, i.e.:

```
from=/tmp/a to=/tmp/b copy
```

Then you could just use `${from}` and `${to}` within the `copy()` function. Just note that you should then *always* pass all parameters. Otherwise, a random variable may leak into the function.

```
from= to=/tmp/b copy   # safe
to=/tmp/b copy         # unsafe: ${from} may be declared elsewhere
```

---

If you have bash 4.1 (I think), you can also try using associative arrays. It will allow you to pass named arguments but it *will* be ugly. Something like:

```
args=( [from]=/tmp/a [to]=/tmp/b )
copy args
```

And then in `copy()`, you'd need to [grab the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069188/how-to-pass-an-associative-array-as-argument-to-a-function-in-bash).

Comment: The 'local' method: copy from=/tmp/a to=/tmp/b; looks very similar to how one would call a Make target 'copy' and pass it two new environment variables (from and to). I really like the syntax similarities.

Comment: @claytontstanley: yes, that was the intent ;).

Comment: I use the global variable approach for optional arguments, but I name said variable after the function and clear it within the function after it's checked. For example, if I have an optional prompt for `get_input()`, then I'd use `gi_prompt="blah blah blah"`, and in the function, `unset gi_prompt`. By namespacing everything related to the function, this prevents leaks and naming conflicts while allowing some flexibility.

Comment: When you implement the long parser example I think you need to shift 2 to move to the next argument pair.

Comment: I really like the cleanliness of the `local "${@}"` solution, with the stipulation of having to pass in named arguments in the form name=value. Especially since you can reset them first, as well as set defaults, because it becomes self-documenting if it's at the beginning of the function.

Comment: I like the use of long parser but I do have question about this `echo 'Missing parameter argument.' >&2`. When does that executed ? I don't know what does that mean ?

Comment: @KalibZen, I'm not sure why I've done it like this, perhaps as an optimization. For a long option, you need two array elements: $1 with the option and $2 with the argument. After reading them, you need to shift both out of the way. Instead of checking whether I had two early in the loop, I first shift $1 (which I know I have), then I shift again to get $2 out of the way. If shift returns false, it means that there weren't $2 in the first place.

Answer (score 19):

You can always pass things through the environment:

```
#!/bin/sh
foo() {
  echo arg1 = "$arg1"
  echo arg2 = "$arg2"
}

arg1=banana arg2=apple foo
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be the top response? This looks like the cleanest solution

Comment: @committedandroider the word 'clean' is cancer and we should stop using it. it makes no claims and conveys nothing more than a preference.  if you defy convention, you've probably lost the argument already. that's not 'clean' design. you've forced some additional pollution of the global space. you've lost the ability to control your defaults and/or put the onus on the caller. and remember; those variables hang around. more typing and all to save a peek at the def or help? no, you still need to. 'clean' isn't an argument. I'm grandstanding, not chastising. not meaning to anyway.

Comment: tldr; this design trades function in the form of encapsulation for a bit of syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 11):

All you have to do is name variables on the way in to the function call.

```bash
function test() {
    echo $a
}

a='hello world' test
#prove variable didnt leak
echo $a .
```

[image]

This isn't just a feature of functions, you could have that function in it's own script and call `a='hello world' test.sh` and it would work just the same

---

As an extra little bit of fun, you can combine this method with positional arguments (say you were making a script and some users mightn't know the variable names).
Heck, why not let it have defaults for those arguments too? Well sure, easy peasy!

```bash
function test2() {
    [[ -n "$1" ]] && local a="$1"; [[ -z "$a" ]] && local a='hi'
    [[ -n "$2" ]] && local b="$2"; [[ -z "$b" ]] && local b='bye'
    echo $a $b
}

#see the defaults
test2

#use positional as usual
test2 '' there
#use named parameter
a=well test2
#mix it up
b=one test2 nice

#prove variables didnt leak
echo $a $b .
```

[image]

Note that if `test` was its own script, you don't need to use the `local` keyword.

Answer (score 4):

Shell functions have full access to any variable available in their calling scope, *except* for those variable names that are used as local variables inside the function itself. In addition, any non-local variable set within a function is available on the outside after the function has been called. Consider the following example:

```
A=aaa
B=bbb

echo "A=$A B=$B C=$C"

example() {
    echo "example(): A=$A B=$B C=$C"

    A=AAA
    local B=BBB
    C=CCC

    echo "example(): A=$A B=$B C=$C"
}

example

echo "A=$A B=$B C=$C"
```

This snippet has the following output:

```
A=aaa B=bbb C=
example(): A=aaa B=bbb C=
example(): A=AAA B=BBB C=CCC
A=AAA B=bbb C=CCC
```

The obvious disadvantage of this approach is that functions are not self-contained any more and that setting a variable outside a function may have unintended side-effects. It would also make things harder if you wanted to pass data to a function without assigning it to a variable first, since this function is not using positional parameters any more.

The most common way to handle this is to use *local variables* for arguments and any temporary variable within a function:

```
example() {
   local A="$1" B="$2" C="$3" TMP="/tmp"

   ...
}
```

This avoids polluting the shell namespace with function-local variables.

Answer (score 3):

I was personally hoping to see some sort of syntax like

```
func(a b){
    echo $a
    echo $b
}
```

But since that's not a thing, and a I see quite a few references to global variables (not without the caveat of scoping and naming conflicts), I'll share my approach.

Using the `copy` function from [Michal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12128447/1175714):

```
copy(){
    cp $from $to
}
from=/tmp/a
to=/tmp/b
copy
```

This is bad, because `from` and `to` are such broad words that any number of functions could use this. You could quickly end up with a naming conflict or a "leak" on your hands.

```
letter(){
    echo "From: $from"
    echo "To:   $to"
    echo
    echo "$1"
}

to=Emily
letter "Hello Emily, you're fired for missing two days of work."

# Result:
#   From: /tmp/a
#   To:   Emily

#   Hello Emily, you're fired for missing two days of work.
```

So my approach is to "namespace" them. I name the variable after the function and delete it after the function is done with it. Of course, I only use it for optional values that have default values. Otherwise, I just use positional args.

```
copy(){
    if [[ $copy_from ]] && [[ $copy_to ]]; then
        cp $copy_from $copy_to
        unset copy_from copy_to
    fi
}
copy_from=/tmp/a
copy_to=/tmp/b
copy # Copies /tmp/a to /tmp/b
copy # Does nothing, as it ought to
letter "Emily, you're 'not' re-hired for the 'not' bribe ;)"
# From: (no /tmp/a here!)
# To:

# Emily, you're 'not' re-hired for the 'not' bribe ;)
```

I would make a terrible boss...

---

In practice, my function names are more elaborate than "copy" or "letter".

The most recent example to my memory is `get_input()`, which has `gi_no_sort` and `gi_prompt`.

- `gi_no_sort` is a true/false value that determines whether the completion suggestions are sorted or not. Defaults to true
- `gi_prompt` is a string that is...well, that's self-explanatory. Defaults to "".

The actual arguments the function takes are the source of the aforementioned 'completion suggestions' for the input prompt, and as said list is taken from `$@` in the function, the "named args" are optional<sup>[1]</sup>, and there's no obvious way to distinguish between a string meant as a completion and a boolean/prompt-message, or really anything space-separated in bash, for that matter<sup>[2]</sup>; the above solution ended up saving me a *lot* of trouble.

notes:

1. So a hard-coded `shift` and `$1`, `$2`, etc. are out of the question.
2. E.g. is `"0 Enter a command: {1..9} $(ls)"` a value of `0`, `"Enter a command:"`, and a set of `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 <directory contents>`? Or are `"0"`, `"Enter"`, `"a"`, and `"command:"` part of that set as well? Bash will assume the latter whether you like it or not.

Answer (score 2):

I think I have a solution for you.
With a few tricks you can actually pass named parameters to functions, along with arrays.

The method I developed allows you to access parameters passed to a function like this:

```
testPassingParams() {

    @var hello
    l=4 @array anArrayWithFourElements
    l=2 @array anotherArrayWithTwo
    @var anotherSingle
    @reference table   # references only work in bash >=4.3
    @params anArrayOfVariedSize

    test "$hello" = "$1" && echo correct
    #
    test "${anArrayWithFourElements[0]}" = "$2" && echo correct
    test "${anArrayWithFourElements[1]}" = "$3" && echo correct
    test "${anArrayWithFourElements[2]}" = "$4" && echo correct
    # etc...
    #
    test "${anotherArrayWithTwo[0]}" = "$6" && echo correct
    test "${anotherArrayWithTwo[1]}" = "$7" && echo correct
    #
    test "$anotherSingle" = "$8" && echo correct
    #
    test "${table[test]}" = "works"
    table[inside]="adding a new value"
    #
    # I'm using * just in this example:
    test "${anArrayOfVariedSize[*]}" = "${*:10}" && echo correct
}

fourElements=( a1 a2 "a3 with spaces" a4 )
twoElements=( b1 b2 )
declare -A assocArray
assocArray[test]="works"

testPassingParams "first" "${fourElements[@]}" "${twoElements[@]}" "single with spaces" assocArray "and more... " "even more..."

test "${assocArray[inside]}" = "adding a new value"
```

In other words, not only you can call your parameters by their names (which makes up for a more readable core), you can actually pass arrays (and references to variables - this feature works only in bash 4.3 though)! Plus, the mapped variables are all in the local scope, just as $1 (and others).

The code that makes this work is pretty light and works both in bash 3 and bash 4 (these are the only versions I've tested it with). If you're interested in more tricks like this that make developing with bash much nicer and easier, you can take a look at my [Bash Infinity Framework](https://github.com/niieani/bash-oo-framework), the code below was developed for that purpose.

```
Function.AssignParamLocally() {
    local commandWithArgs=( $1 )
    local command="${commandWithArgs[0]}"

    shift

    if [[ "$command" == "trap" || "$command" == "l="* || "$command" == "_type="* ]]
    then
        paramNo+=-1
        return 0
    fi

    if [[ "$command" != "local" ]]
    then
        assignNormalCodeStarted=true
    fi

    local varDeclaration="${commandWithArgs[1]}"
    if [[ $varDeclaration == '-n' ]]
    then
        varDeclaration="${commandWithArgs[2]}"
    fi
    local varName="${varDeclaration%%=*}"

    # var value is only important if making an object later on from it
    local varValue="${varDeclaration#*=}"

    if [[ ! -z $assignVarType ]]
    then
        local previousParamNo=$(expr $paramNo - 1)

        if [[ "$assignVarType" == "array" ]]
        then
            # passing array:
            execute="$assignVarName=( \"\${@:$previousParamNo:$assignArrLength}\" )"
            eval "$execute"
            paramNo+=$(expr $assignArrLength - 1)

            unset assignArrLength
        elif [[ "$assignVarType" == "params" ]]
        then
            execute="$assignVarName=( \"\${@:$previousParamNo}\" )"
            eval "$execute"
        elif [[ "$assignVarType" == "reference" ]]
        then
            execute="$assignVarName=\"\$$previousParamNo\""
            eval "$execute"
        elif [[ ! -z "${!previousParamNo}" ]]
        then
            execute="$assignVarName=\"\$$previousParamNo\""
            eval "$execute"
        fi
    fi

    assignVarType="$__capture_type"
    assignVarName="$varName"
    assignArrLength="$__capture_arrLength"
}

Function.CaptureParams() {
    __capture_type="$_type"
    __capture_arrLength="$l"
}

alias @trapAssign='Function.CaptureParams; trap "declare -i \"paramNo+=1\"; Function.AssignParamLocally \"\$BASH_COMMAND\" \"\$@\"; [[ \$assignNormalCodeStarted = true ]] && trap - DEBUG && unset assignVarType && unset assignVarName && unset assignNormalCodeStarted && unset paramNo" DEBUG; '
alias @param='@trapAssign local'
alias @reference='_type=reference @trapAssign local -n'
alias @var='_type=var @param'
alias @params='_type=params @param'
alias @array='_type=array @param'
```

Answer (score 0):

Arguments get sent to functions as an tuple of individual items, so they have no names as such, just positions. this allows some interesting possibilities like below, but it does mean that you are stuck with $1. $2, etc. as to whether to map them to better names, the question comes down to how big the function is, and how much clearer it will make reading the code. if its complex, then mapping meaningful names ($BatchID, $FirstName, $SourceFilePath) is a good idea. for simple stuff though, it probably isn't necessary. I certianly wouldn't bother if you are using names like $arg1.

now, if you just want to echo back the parameters, you can iterate over them:

```
for $arg in "$@"
do
  echo "$arg"
done
```

just a fun fact; unless you are processing a list, you are probably interested in somthing more useful

Answer (score 0):

this is an older topic, but still i'd like to share the function below (requires bash 4). It parses named arguments and sets the variables in the scripts environment. Just make sure you have sane default values for all parameters you need. The export statement at the end could also just be an eval. It's great in combination with shift to extend existing scripts which already take a few positional parameters and you dont want to change the syntax, but still add some flexibility.

```
parseOptions()
{
  args=("$@")
  for opt in "${args[@]}"; do
    if [[ ! "${opt}" =~ .*=.* ]]; then
      echo "badly formatted option \"${opt}\" should be: option=value, stopping..."
      return 1
    fi
    local var="${opt%%=*}"
    local value="${opt#*=}"
    export ${var}="${value}"
  done
  return 0
}
```