# Assigning variables values in a better way

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a written a bash script which uses number of parameters.
I have assigned variables in the following format.

```
x=$1
y=$2
z=$3
k=$4
```

The arguments are optional, and it runs without them as well
For example :

```
./myscript.sh
./myscript.sh x y ...
```

both cases are working fine.

I am looking for a better approach, from design point of view as I don't like the way the variables are getting the value.

it will not look nice if in the future my arguments increase till 9

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there's anything much simpler than that. There's no one-liner to set multiple variables.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash/14203146#14203146.

Comment: If your command takes 9 arguments, you probably have bigger issues than 9 assignment statements at the top of your script.

Comment: @Barmar Of course there is one: `read x y z k <<<"$@"`. Simple, clean. Read my answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to avoid positional arguments in bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128296/is-there-a-way-to-avoid-positional-arguments-in-bash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `read` combined with herestring and the quote reconstruction ability of `printf`:

```
read x y z k <<<$(printf " %q" "$@")
```

By example:

```
$ cat example.bash
#!/bin/bash
read x y z k <<<$(printf " %q" "$@")
echo "x=[$x]"
echo "y=[$y]"
echo "z=[$z]"
echo "k=[$k]"

$ ./example.bash a b "c d"
x=[a]
y=[b]
z=[c d]
k=[]
```

So, what's going on here? Let's work from the inside out.

`printf " %q" "$@"` [quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10836225/2908724) the arguments it's given in a way equivalent to the original command line arguments. Without this quoting reconstruction, command line arguments with spaces would be treated as *separate arguments even if originally quoted*. To see what I mean, try `read x y z w <<<"$@"`: z is assigned "c" and k is assigned "d".

`read` receives the reconstituted command line, then assigns every non-escaped-space separated string into the given variables, left to right.

Back to our example:

- `"$@"` is essentially `a b "c d"`
- `printf " %q" "$@"` is `a b c\ d`
- `read x y z k <<<"a b c\ d"` is a hard-coded representation of what you want.

While this is compact and extensible, it's also tricky. If your script takes arguments representing *options* (script behavior changes based on presence of absence of said arguments) then I'd suggest using `getopts`. If, however, your script takes many arguments representing *values* (like inputs into a matrix calculation) then reading into an array (`read -a`) might be easier to understand.

---

You might also want to handle the case where no command line arguments are provided. That requires a slight elaboration:

```
read x y z k <<<$([ 0 -eq $# ] && echo '' || printf " %q" "$@")
```

In this variant, the number of arguments are checked and if there are some, then the printf requoting business is performed.

Comment: This doesn't work with new lines: `./script a b "c d" "*" LIST $'f\ng'`.

Comment: Nicely done; one thing to watch out for is that if there are more arguments than variables, the last variable (`k` in this case) will receive a space-separated list of _all remaining_ arguments.
@sorontar: More generally, this won't work with strings containing control characters (`printf %q` represents them as `$'…'` strings); however, that's rarely a concern when passing arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use this construct.

```
for i in x y z k 
do
    eval $i='$1'
    shift
done
```

Comment: This could get tricky if any of the arguments contain whitespace or other metacharacters.

Comment: Nicely done. @KeithThompson: While being wary of `eval` in general is advisable, _this_ use seems to be safe, thanks to the single quotes: neither whitespace nor metacharacters in arguments break the assignment (though I'd recommend using `declare $i="$1"` instead so as not to get into the habit of using `eval`).

Answer (score 1):

**If the number of arguments is *open-ended*, you're better off using an *array*** - possibly even `"$@"`, the array of all arguments, directly (to copy all arguments to a custom array, use something like `args=( "$@" )`).

<sup>You can learn more about Bash arrays [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays).

Also, the solution below demonstrates array techniques by employing an auxiliary array to create the individual variables.</sup>

That said, **if you *do* need *distinct variable names***, here's a robust approach:

<sup>This approach is probably more indirect than it needs to be, in the interest of parameterization and error handling.

See [rené's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40010773/45375) for the gist of this approach.</sup>

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Declare the up to 9 variable names to assign to, using a helper array.
varNames=( a b c d e f g h i )

# Exit, if more arguments than available variables were specified.
(( $# > ${#varNames[@]} )) && { echo "Too many arguments." >&2; exit 2; }

# Assign to the variables in sequence, looping over the variable-names array.
for varName in "${varNames[@]}"; do
  (( $# )) || break   # Break, if there are no more arguments.
  declare "$varName"="$1"
  shift
done
```

To then print the resulting variables, using [variable indirection](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Indirection):

```
# Print all variable values, using indirection.
for varName in "${varNames[@]}"; do  
  echo "Value of \$$varName: '${!varName}'"
done
```

Comment: @sorontar: I probably tried to show too much at once - simplified now. Still not simple, but it does have one distinct advantage: it works robustly, unlike your `<<<"$@"` solutions. If using an _array_ is an option, there is no need to resort to `read -a` or `readarray` - simply copy `"$@`" as follows: `arr=( "$@" )` (as you've just discovered) - which brings us back to my very first suggestions at the top.

Answer (score 1):

Skip positional parameters altogether, by naming your parameters on the command line:

```
$ cat example.bash
#!/bin/bash
declare x=1013 y=242 z k
declare "$@" >/dev/null
echo "x=[$x]"
echo "y=[$y]"
echo "z=[$z]"
echo "k=[$k]"

$ ./example.bash x="b" z="c d" k=$'e\nf'
x=[b]
y=[242]
z=[c d]
k=[e
f]
```

The first `declare` acts as a safety net and initializes all your intended variables with default values. The second `declare` pulls in the named variables on the command line, treating them as variable assignment. Variables not supplied on the command line keep their initialized, default value (as in the example, `y` is not passed and therefore gets its default of `242`). Variables other than those declared will be available in your script. This may or may not be desired.

Answer (score 0):

Using "shift" you can get command line arguments as named options.
See [Handling positional parameters](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/posparams)

```
while :
do
    case "$1" in
      -f | --file)
          file="$2"   
          shift 2
          ;;
      -h | --help)
          display_help  # Call your function
          # no shifting needed here, we're done.
          exit 0
          ;;
      -u | --user)
          username="$2" # You may want to check validity of $2
          shift 2
          ;;
      -v | --verbose)
          #  It's better to assign a string, than a number like "verbose=1"
          #  because if you're debugging the script with "bash -x" code like this:
          #
          #    if [ "$verbose" ] ...
          #
          #  You will see:
          #
          #    if [ "verbose" ] ...
          #
          #  Instead of cryptic
          #
          #    if [ "1" ] ...
          #
          verbose="verbose"
          shift
          ;;
      --) # End of all options
          shift
          break;
          ;;
      -*) # Wrong option
          echo "Error: Unknown option: $1" >&2
          exit 1
          ;;
      *)  # No more options
          break
          ;;
    esac
done
```

Or you can use [getopts](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial).

Comment: This is simpler than 4 assignments?

Comment: It's more flexible and powerful, but not simpler.

Comment: It also makes a lot of assumptions that aren't present in the question.

Comment: The question was about a "better" approach. May be it's not better, it's different; it can be useful if parameter number increases.

Answer (score 0):

In no case is it possible to assign a zero byte `$'\0'` to a variable.
A string in `c` ends in a zero byte, it could not contain a zero byte.
No further discussion of this issue follows.

#### Variables with No spaces, tabs or newlines

If you don't need to allow spaces or newlines, this will work robustly:

```
if (IFS=''; reg=$'[ \t\n]'; [[ "$*" =~ $reg ]] ); then
    echo "$0: error: input contains spaces, tabs or newlines" >&2
    exit 1
fi

if (( $# != 4 )); then
    echo "$0: error: we need 4 arguments"
    exit 2
fi

read x y z k <<<"$@"

printf 'x="%s" y="%s" z="%s" k="%s"\n' "$x" "$y" "$z" "$k"
```

If the input has either spaces, tabs or newlines the script will barf.

Use it as:

```
$ script one two t33 f44
x="one"   y="two"   z="t33"   k="f44"
```

#### Variables with no newlines

To make it accept spaces and tabs, we need to extend the read to:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' x y z k < <(printf '%s\n' "$@")

$ ./script $'o\tne' 't wo' t33 f44
x="o    ne"   y="t wo"   z="t33"   k="f44"
```

One reasonable alternative is to use Associative Arrays (no newlines):

```
if (IFS=''; reg=$'[\n]'; [[ "$*" =~ $reg ]] ); then 
    echo "$0: error: input contains newlines" >&2
    exit 1
fi

varlist=(x y z k)
n=${#varlist[@]}

if (( $# != $n )); then
echo "$0: error: we need $n arguments"
exit 2
fi

declare -A arr
for i in ${varlist[@]}; do
IFS='' read "arr[$i]" 
done < <(printf '%s\n' "$@")

for i in ${!arr[@]}; do
printf '%s="%s"    ' "$i" "${arr[$i]}"
done
echo
```

Some changes allow to use directly variable names:

```
if (IFS=''; reg=$'[\n]'; [[ "$*" =~ $reg ]] ); then 
    echo "$0: error: input contains newlines" >&2
    exit 1
fi

varlist=(x y z k)
n=${#varlist[@]}

if (( $# != $n )); then
    echo "$0: error: we need $n arguments"
    exit 2
fi

for i in ${varlist[@]}; do
    IFS='' read "$i"
done < <(printf '%s\n' "$@")

for i in ${varlist[@]}; do
    printf '%s="%s"    ' "$i" "${!i}"
done
echo
```

And a final adaptation allow to finally accept also newlines:

```
varlist=(x y z k)
n=${#varlist[@]}

if (( $# != $n )); then
    echo "$0: error: we need $n arguments"
    exit 2
fi

for i in ${varlist[@]}; do
    IFS='' read -d '' "$i"
done < <(printf '%s\0' "$@")

for i in ${varlist[@]}; do
    printf '%s="%s"    ' "$i" "${!i}"
done
echo
```