# How to use environment variables in package.json

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm, package.json

Because we don't want sensitive data in the project code, including the package.json file, using environment variables would be a logical choice in my opinion.

Example package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "accounting": "~0.4.0",
    "async": "~1.4.2",
    "my-private-module":"git+https://${BB_USER}:${BB_PASS}@bitbucket.org/foo/bar.git"
```

Is this possible?

The question is *not* if this is *wise* or *not good*, just **if it's possible**.

Comment: Did you found a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 73):

In case you use `.env` file, let's use `grep` or `eval` to get a value environment variable from the .env file.

Updated `start2` as @Paul suggested:

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=$(grep NODE_ENV .env | cut -d '=' -f2) some_script",
    "start2": "eval $(grep '^NODE_ENV' .env) && some_script"
}
```

Comment: This should be the top comment because it perfectly solves this.

Comment: I've been using this but when you start using this in multiple places it gets very verbose. Is there a library that can make this shorter?

Comment: this is awesome, thanks. it works in "scripts". unfortunately it doesn't work in "config" which would be really useful. any idea why?

Comment: nm - it's the shell, not npm

Comment: You can also shorten this to `eval $(grep '^NODE_ENV' .env) && some_script`

Comment: Two issues with this. 1: The question was about dependencies, not scripts. Scripts run in the shell so using an environment variable in a script is very different from using one in a regular package.json value. 2: (Maybe I'm missing something here, but) getting an environment variable's value via grep seems like a complicated way of just doing `$NODE_ENV`. Further, if `NODE_ENV` is already defined as an environment variable, then it doesn't need to be redefined. Seems like it just saves you from doing `source .env` (and you could use something like direnv to do it automatically for you).

Comment: Is there any way to chain these like this: `eval $(grep -Ev '(^AWS_PROFILE|^AWS_REGION)' .env)` so that I don't have to do this: `eval $(grep '^AWS_PROFILE' .env) && eval $(grep '^AWS_REGION' .env)`

Comment: Shocked this has so many upvotes. Using `eval` to execute content from a file is a TERRIBLE idea. Hopefully you have time to find a new job before some malicious actor injects their `mysql -e "DROP DATABASE prod;"; NODE_ENV="123"` `.env` file into your company's build pipeline.

Comment: what about in windows

Answer (score 24):

I have similar but different requirement.  For me, I want to use environment variables in the scripts.

Instead of using the environment variables directly in package.json, I do:

```
"some-script": "./scripts/some-script.sh",
```

And in some-script.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

source .env

npm run some-other-script -- --prop=$SOME_ENV_VAR
```

Comment: Could you tell how do you access `prop` in `some-other-script`?

Comment: It's been a while.  Can you follow the highest voted answer here to see if that works? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499472/specify-command-line-arguments-like-name-value-pairs-for-shell-script

Comment: bash scripts doesn't work on widnows `'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: I needed to add `source .env` and it works as expected. Thank you

Answer (score 10):

Here's how I managed to work around `package.json` to achieve the same purpose. It uses a script that reads from a custom section of `package.json` for URL modules, interpolates environment variables in them, and installs them with `npm install --no-save` (the `--no-save` could be omitted, depending on the usecase).

As a bonus: it tries to read the env variable from `.env.json`, which can be gitignore'd, and very useful for development.

1. Create a script that will read from a custom section of `package.json`

`env-dependencies.js`

```
const execSync = require('child_process').execSync
const pkg = require('./package.json')

if (!pkg.envDependencies) {
  return process.exit(0)
}

let env = Object.assign({}, process.env)

if (typeof pkg.envDependencies.localJSON === 'string') {
  try {
    Object.assign(env, require(pkg.envDependencies.localJSON))
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`Could not read or parse pkg.envDependencies.localJSON. Processing with env only.`)
  }
}

if (typeof pkg.envDependencies.urls === 'undefined') {
  console.log(`pkg.envDependencies.urls not found or empty. Passing.`)
  process.exit(0)
}

if (
  !Array.isArray(pkg.envDependencies.urls) ||
  !(pkg.envDependencies.urls.every(url => typeof url === 'string'))
) {
  throw new Error(`pkg.envDependencies.urls should have a signature of String[]`)
}

const parsed = pkg.envDependencies.urls
  .map(url => url.replace(/\${([0-9a-zA-Z_]*)}/g, (_, varName) => {
    if (typeof env[varName] === 'string') {
      return env[varName]
    } else {
      throw new Error(`Could not read env variable ${varName} in url ${url}`)
    }
  }))
  .join(' ')

try {
  execSync('npm install --no-save ' + parsed, { stdio: [0, 1, 2] })
  process.exit(0)
} catch (err) {
  throw new Error('Could not install pkg.envDependencies. Are you sure the remote URLs all have a package.json?')
}
```

2. Add a `"postinstall": "node env-dependencies.js"` to your `package.json`, that way it will be run on every `npm install`
3. Add your private git repos to `package.json` using the URLs you want (note: they all must have a `package.json` at root!):

```
"envDependencies": {
  "localJSON": "./.env.json",
  "urls": [
    "git+https://${GITHUB_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN}@github.com/user/repo#semver:^2.0.0"
  ]
},
```

(the semver specifier `#semver:^2.0.0` can be omitted, but refers to a git tag, which can be very useful, as it makes your git server a fully-fledge package manager)

4. `npm install`

Answer (score 8):

No, it's not possible. You should access the repo using `git+ssh`, and store a private key in `~/.ssh`.

Your line then looks like:

```
"my-private-module":"git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/foo/bar.git"
```

Which doesn't contain anything sensitive.

Comment: Additionally you can even use a different ssh key and ssh config for this purpose, not the usual id_rsa.

Comment: Yep, I'd recommend that. (I did mean that with "store *a* private key", but could be clearer.)

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, it's Heroku :-S. So should be a custom build pack I guess. Docker will be ultimate environment in the end I think. Need to do this! Regards!

Comment: This .npmrc is able to interpret environment variables though! But was not able to combine, not mend to use it for these purposes I think...

Answer (score 5):

No it isn't possible as npm does not treat any string values as any kind of templates.

It may be better to just use `git+ssh` (if your provider supports it) with an ssh agent.

Comment: anybody using docker for deployment shouldn't use this method

Comment: @monothorn - what could be a better way to do that? Do you have any suggestion... I am still figuring out if we don't use ssh, what could be a better way.

Comment: @Ashmah HTTPS is the way to go but again you will have to restrict access for the token you have generated and make sure the repo is private. Other than these, you will have to understand if there are any more security concerns.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same need and my solution was based on @Long Nguyen's [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60701796/897170). This way, I can only rely on what's defined on the .env file.

.env

```
...
SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true
...
```

package.json

```
...
"scripts": {
  "test": "yarn cross-env $(grep SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK ../../.env) react-app-rewired test --watchAll=false"
}
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use environment values to inject in your package.json like this:

> Any environment variables that start with npm_config_ will be interpreted as a configuration parameter. For example, putting npm_config_foo=bar in your environment will set the foo configuration parameter to bar. Any environment configurations that are not given a value will be given the value of true. Config values are case-insensitive, so NPM_CONFIG_FOO=bar will work the same.

https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#environment-variables

Comment: This is for setting variables to be uses by npm scripts - similar to config section in package.json. These variables can't be read by package.json

Answer (score 2):

You can install package https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-cmd
and all your envs from `.env` file will be visible
ie:

./.env:

```
ENV1=THANKS
ENV2=FOR ALL
ENV3=THE FISH
```

Package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "env-cmd pact-broker can-i-deploy --broker-token=${ENV1}"
  }
```

or another example from your question:

```
    "my-private-module":"env-cmd git+https://${BB_USER}:${BB_PASS}@bitbucket.org/foo/bar.git"
```

Comment: From the [env-cmd README](https://github.com/toddbluhm/env-cmd#-x-expands-vars-in-arguments): *"You must escape the `$` character with `\ ` or your terminal might try to auto expand it before passing it to `env-cmd`"*. He gives an example npm script: `env-cmd -x node index.js --arg=\\$VAR`. Also see https://github.com/toddbluhm/env-cmd-examples/blob/master/examples/env-file-env-expansion/package.json

Answer (score 1):

### If you're running node inside a Docker container

Use Docker Compose to inject the env variable

```
app:
  environment:
    - NODE_ENV=staging
```

Run your package.json script from your Dockerfile

```
CMD [ "npm", "run", "start" ]
```

Use `echo` or `printenv`

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "node -r dotenv/config app.js dotenv_config_path=/run/secrets/$(echo $NODE_ENV)"
    "start": "node -r dotenv/config app.js dotenv_config_path=/run/secrets/$(printenv NODE_ENV)"
}
```

Don't use this for sensitive env variables. It's a really good way to point to a Docker secrets file (like this example shows).

Comment: Also works without a docker container (for me)

Answer (score 0):

For complicated environment variables, you can use
https://stedolan.github.io/jq/
to access JSON file (env file at your case)
JSON file could be something like

```
{
    "env" :
     {  
            "username" : "1345345",
            "Groups" :  [],
            "arraytest" : [
               {
                  "yes" : "1",
                  "no" : "0"
               }
             ]
     }
}
```

so the script could be something like this to access yes value

```
"scripts": {
    "yes": "jq [].arraytest[0].yes?"
}
```