# Hiding the token for a private repo in package.json

Tags: node.js, package.json

I have a private repo that is used in my project something like 
    "myPrivateRepo":"git+https://oauth2:SOMESECRET@git.github.com/privaterepo.git"

I will be deploying this project as a public repo. How can i hide the `SOMESECRET` ? 
I tried to use enviornmentVariable but did not work out.

```
"myPrivateRepo":"${PrivateRepoUrl}"
```

Please assist.

Comment: Maybe explain why environment variables didn't work out? They are the normal way to handle this, and most people are going to want to suggest that approach.

Comment: I have a react project created using create-react-app. Then added a .env file to the root location, within the file i added PrivateRepoUrl=someURL. When trying to do npm install; i get the following error - code EINVALIDTAGNAME
npm ERR! Invalid tag name "${PrivateRepoUrl}": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.

Comment: Sorry I just realised that you're trying to use env vars inside package.json, yep you're right that isn't straightforward. Can you access the private repo via ssh instead? Like this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34650617/1058314

Comment: Yea , i can access via ssh also. Just saw another approach - https://stackoverflow.com/a/40312033/893217 , what do you think ?

Comment: I tried out the SSH option, and it worked well on local computer. Now the issue is i need to deploy on Heroku, and i dont think Heroku would provide the public key which i could whitelist on GIT

Comment: Helpful? https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/simon0191/custom-ssh-key-buildpack

Answer (score 0):

You should use Vault for this. You can download it from here: https://www.vaultproject.io/downloads.html

Learn more about vault here: https://learn.hashicorp.com/vault/

There are others tool as well which you can select as per your comfort.