# How to use system variables in package.json dependencies in my react project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, git, npm-install, package.json

In my react project, I am trying to install a private package using the git URL. I want to specify a branch name in the URL which will be dynamic.

In the `package.json` file, when I hardcode the branch name it works fine.

```
dependencies: {
    ...
    my-package: "git+https://<git-url-of-my-package>#develop",
    ...
}
```

The problem is when I use the variable, it does not work as expected.

```
dependencies: {
    ...
    my-package: "git+https://<git-url-of-my-package>#$BRANCH_NAME",
    ...
}
```

I am not sure here how to pass the branch name dynamically and I need some help in understanding the same.

Note: I don't want to install `<my-package>` using another npm script. I want to install it with other dependencies using `npm-install`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm using MacOs and linux

Comment: Using variables in a regular dependency is not possible as far as I know, but if you use a `postinstall` script, a script can be run automatically after calling `npm install`. An example close to your situation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56639755/15706847

Comment: Using environment variables can be done in scripts section. So you can create a preinstall script https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/scripts that pulls the code into some directory. And then point to the local directory in your dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Check URL as dependency, You can specify tarball URL

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#urls-as-dependencies

Check This also - Using the git urls with specific branch or commit version in package.json does not work - https://github.com/yWorks/svg2pdf.js/issues/102

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it:

1.Set an environment variable before running npm install:
bash

export BRANCH_NAME=develop
npm install

Update your package.json:
json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "my-package": "git+https://<git-url-of-my-package>#${BRANCH_NAME}"
  }
}
```

Run npm install.

This way, the $BRANCH_NAME will be replaced with the actual value of the environment variable BRANCH_NAME during the installation process.

Ensure that the environment variable BRANCH_NAME is set appropriately before running npm install. You can adjust this value dynamically based on your requirements.