# How to use .env variable in npm script

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, dotenv

In my .env I have the following variable:

```
SHOPIFY_STORE_URL=mystore.myshopify.com
```

Now I want to use this variable in a npm script:

```
  "scripts": {
    "shopify-login": "shopify login --store=SHOPIFY_STORE_URL",
  },
```

so `$ npm run shopify-login` should execute `$ shopify login --store=mystore.myshopify.com`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What about using `$SHOPIFY_STORE_URL`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34650527/how-to-use-environment-variables-in-package-json

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use environment variables in package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34650527/how-to-use-environment-variables-in-package-json)

Comment: I don't understand these answers, as they are not clear, how they named their characters in their .env.

Answer (score 2):

When you are on a linux/mac operating system - this should work:

```
# .env
SHOPIFY_STORE_URL=mystore.myshopify.com
```

my test case:

```
  "scripts": {
    "shopify-login": "source .env && echo $SHOPIFY_STORE_URL"
  }
```

your test case:

```
  "scripts": {
    "shopify-login": "source .env && shopify login --store=$SHOPIFY_STORE_URL",
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

For a cross platform answer I found success using [cross-env](https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env).

This lets you reference the environment variable directly regardless of environment, using the `cross-env-shell` command. It also will work if environment variables are not set in a local .env file.
so in your case you could do

```
   "scripts": {
    "shopify-login": "cross-env-shell shopify login --store=$SHOPIFY_STORE_URL",
  },
```

`cross-env-shell` worked rather than the usual `cross-env` module as the `$` symbol is interpreted directly. According to their github:

> If you want to pass to cross-env a command that contains special shell characters that you want interpreted, then use cross-env-shell. Otherwise stick to cross-env.

Comment: cross-env is useful when setting environment variables inline while running node commands across platforms, but it won't read the environment variables in a .env file to populate the node command.