# How to access kubernetes environment variables from package.json?

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes

I am passing some test variables to my pod which has code in nodejs like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: envar-demo
  labels:
    purpose: demonstrate-envars
spec:
  containers:
  - name: envar-demo-container
    image: gcr.io/google-samples/node-hello:1.0
    send:
    - name: DEMO_GREETING
      value: "Hello from the environment"
    - name: DEMO_FAREWELL
      value: "Such a sweet sorrow"
```

I am trying to access the value of these variables from the **package.json** that I have inside my pod but I'm not sure how to do it, if I don't have an .env file from which I can read these variables using grep

Comment: Wondering What's `send` in your manifest??

Comment: I can access the variables from js code using `process.env.DEMO_GREETING`, but I don't know how to do it from package.json

Comment: The manifest looks incorrect. So basically you want the content of a file to be set as environment variable?

Comment: I was already able to send the environment variable and retrieve it from the pod, but only from the .js files and I need to retrieve it from the package.json.
Something like this but with a kubernetes .env:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34650527/how-to-use-environment-variables-in-package-json

Comment: Once your process starts running, these are ordinary environment variables, exactly the same thing as if you ran `export DEMO_GREETING='hello world'` in a local shell.  Does that simplify the setup for you?  What exactly are you trying to do with these variables in `package.json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter how you have set the variable through Kubernetes, export, or just before calling a command. You can get access to it as in the usual bash script.

```
"scripts": {
  "envvar": "echo $TEST_ENV_VAR"
},
```

Then we can run it

```
➜ TEST_ENV_VAR=4342 npm run envvar

> envvar
> echo $TEST_ENV_VAR

4342
```