# How to using .env variable in package.json

Tags: vue.js, testing, command, cypress, package.json

I'm using Cypress to run some tests with my VueJS project.

I just want to run test with browser I want so I made a .env like below

```
BROWSER=edge
```

And in package.json file, I write a command like this:

```
"scripts":{
      "cy:run" : "cypress run --browser %BROWSER%"
}
```

I know I can put the command like this

```
"cy:run" : "cypress run --browser edge"
```

But the reason I created an .env file is when the test is finished, I want to save my test result with the browser's name. So when I change the BROWSER in my .env, after that I just only run npm command.

But it didn't work. Cypress cannot detect which browser I wanted.
I've tried so many ways, including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34650527/how-to-use-environment-variables-in-package-json).

Can anyone tell me how to make it work? Super many thanks.

I've tried with a specific browser, when the test is done, test results save with the name I want, which means BROWSER in .env file is OK to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out, by using [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env)

First I install `cross-env` with `npm i cross-env`

In my `package.json`, I modified like this

```
"scripts":{
   "run:env" : "cross-env BROWSER=\"edge\" npm run cy:run"
   "cy:run" : "cross-env-shell cypress run --browser=$BROWSER"
 }
```

Then I run `npm run run:env`

Everything works now.

The process.env.BROWSER is still usable even I deleted the .env file

Answer (score 0):

You need two dashes for the full "browser" option

```js
"scripts":{
  "cy:run" : "cypress run --browser %BROWSER%"
}
```

or one dash for shortcut "-b"

```js
"scripts":{
  "cy:run" : "cypress run -b %BROWSER%"
}
```

Comment: It was my mistake when typing the question. I've edited my question.

Comment: Both of these examples work, so you must be failing to set up `%BROWSER%`.

Comment: Are you looking for [dotenv package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)? If so, you cannot use `%BROWSER%` on the script with that configuration.

Comment: Yes, I'm using dotenv. So what can I do now? I figured that `cypress run -b %BROWSER% `, it will looking for the system environment variable named BROWSER.  So when I run `set BROWSER=edge` on the cmd, and `cypress run` again, it works. But that's not what I wanted.

Comment: I just add a workaround above.