# How to fetch env var from inside package.json

Tags: reactjs, webpack, environment-variables, package.json

package.json includes:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "export MY_APP_GTAG=UA-123456-1 && node increment-build.js && npm run build-css && node scripts/build.js",
},
```

Index.html includes:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=%MY_APP_GTAG%"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', '%MY_APP_GTAG%');
</script>
```

The value for `MY_APP_GTAG` also exists in my .env file:

```
MY_APP_GTAG=UA-123456-1
```

In the build script, is it possible to fetch the value for `MY_APP_GTAG` from the .env file? Instead of hard-coding the value in package.json.

I've tried

```
  "build": "export MY_APP_GTAG=${process.env.MY_APP_GTAG} && ...",
```

but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60701796/19407815) about setting up your env to be read from the package.json file and post your items in the env.