# How to use env in package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, gitlab, package.json

Let's say I have 1 util repo on gitlab with URL `https://gitlab.com/my-repo/utils.git`

and main repo that uses the utils repo as dependencies. I have 3 environments dev stg and prod for utils and main. How can I select the right branch of utils when I install the package?

Ex:

```
"dependencies": {
  "utils" : "git+https://gitlab.com/my-repo/utils#dev"
}
```

How can I use env to replace dev with stg/prod?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use environment variables in package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34650527/how-to-use-environment-variables-in-package-json)