# Reading an environment var from .env file into package.json script

Tags: javascript, environment-variables, package.json, playwright

I want to be able to use environment variables in an .env file inside a package.json script.

.env file:

```
MY_URL="example.com"

MY_BROWSER='chrome'

USER='xyz'

PASSWORD='123'
```

So instead of :

```
"myscript": "pnpx playwright codegen https://myurl.com",
```

I want something like:

```
"myscript": "pnpx playwright codegen $MY_URL,
```

I've tried using [env-cmd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-cmd) but not getting result I want as the browser opens with no url

Comment: Use process.env.MY_URL

Comment: No, its in package.json

Comment: Seemingly not possible to do in a **good** way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34650527/how-to-use-environment-variables-in-package-json

Comment: I think you might be able to use .env file like this https://playwright.dev/docs/test-parameterize#env-files if it caters to your need

Answer (score 0):

Use `dotenv` and `cross-var` libraries to refer to your `.env` file.

**env file:**

```
MY_URL=https://myrul.com
```

**package.json:**

```js
**  If you are using a simple command.

scripts: {
"command": "dotenv cross-var pnpx playwright codegen %MY_URL%"
}

** If you are using a command with further arguments

scripts: {
"command": "dotenv -- cross-var pnpx playwright codegen %MY_URL%"
}
```

This should work.